# how to resize or crop image during upload in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new with wordpress and I have issue on how to deal in resizing or cropping images during upload.

I have this code already on my customized wordpress plugin:

```
function my_handle_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$set_thu=false) {

  // check to make sure its a successful upload
  if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

  $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );
  if ( is_numeric( $attach_id ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_file_upload', $attach_id );
  }
  return $attach_id;
}


if ( $_FILES ) { 
    $files = $_FILES["img"];  
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {            
        if ($files['name'][$key]) { 
            $file = array( 
                'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                'type' => $files['type'][$key], 
                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key], 
                'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                'size' => $files['size'][$key]
            ); 
            $_FILES = array ("my_file_upload" => $file); 
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {              
                $newupload = my_handle_attachment($file,$pid); 
                // newly uploaded files
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

well, I tried `add_image_size( 'mysize', 300, 300, true );` but I want the original image to be resize.

My issue is that, during upload, the image will be resize or cropped like 300X300. Is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want the original image to be resized? u can access the 'mysize' calling that specific size. For every size set in WP it creates a copy of the original image with that size...

Comment: Thanks for your response @buxbeatz

I failed to include that, I categorised the SIZE. What I want is the size should be specific on that particular size that can be resized/cropped.

Ex.: I have a category for the size of 300x250, 400x350, and 500x450.
What I want is, once the picture uploaded that is set at category 300x250, I don't want a copy of the picture with sizes 400x350 and 500x450. Because if the picture has a copy on each category size, I will end-up storing a great number of pictures.

Answer (score -5):

why don't you crop the desire image in a photo edit application and then upload it.